# readarray names with whitespaces

Tags: arrays, bash, double-quotes

env : GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release

---

list.txt

```
pineapple & pizza
mint & chocolate
broccoli & pizza
```

```
$ readarray -t cursed_food < list.txt
$ for food in ${cursed_food[@]}
> do 
>   echo ${food}
> done
```

---

expected outcome

```
pineapple & pizza
mint & chocolate
broccoli & pizza
```

the outcome

```
pineapple 
& 
pizza
mint 
& 
chocolate
broccoli 
& 
pizza
```

I googled for a while but it seems like my shell works differently than everyone else.
What am I doing wrong in here?
I really don't wan't to quote every lines of `list.txt`.

Comment: Use `"${cursed_food[@]}"` instead of `${cursed_food[@]}`

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong in here?

You are not checking your script with shellcheck. If you would, you would know that, from https://www.shellcheck.net/ :

```
Line 1:
readarray -t cursed_food < list.txt
^-- SC2148 (error): Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.
 
Line 2:
for food in ${cursed_food[@]}
            ^-- SC2068 (error): Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
 
Line 4:
   echo ${food}
        ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
   echo "${food}"
```

> I really don't want to quote every lines of list.txt.

Changing input has *nothing* to do with how it is parsed. You have to change the way you *use* the variable, not the input.